# Access File on a mapped network drive (Windows)

Tags: java, swt, java-io, filedialog

I'm having a problem while accessing a file that resides on a mapped network drive. 
I have a RCP application that runs on a Windows Client and I want to offer the user the possibility to import settings from a file the user can pick with a SWT `FileDialog`. As long as the file is on the local PC where the application runs there are no problems, but when I want to import the settings from a file that resides on a mapped network drive I get a `FileNotFoundException` although the file does exist.
One thing I could find out is that this is a problem that the drive mapping is only valid for the logged in user, but the application needs the UNC path to access it.
So what possibilities do I have to solve this problem? Does SWT offer the possibility to retrieve the UNC path of a file that resides on a mapped network drive?
The only solution I found is that I could use the SWING `JFileChooser`, but I don't like the way this dialog is rendered. It just doesn't suit into my application and SWT uses the Windows native file dialog which looks much better ...

Any other suggestion I could try out?

Comment: So does selecting the file with the `FileDialog` fail or attempting to read the file you got from the `FileDialog` with an `InputStream`/`BufferedReader`/etc.?

Comment: Yes I create a File from the path I get from the `FileDialog` and try then to read the file with a `BufferedReader`. I also already called the function `exists()` and it returns false ...

Comment: Just tested it on a mapped network drive and it works just fine.

Comment: What path are you getting from `FileDialog`? Something like `Z:\filepath` or `\\server\share\filepath`

Comment: OK I think I could find my problem ... I used `URI.createFileURI(filePath);` to convert the string into a file URI and then later when I create my File I just used `uri.path()`, but this wasn't enough I need to call `uri.devicePath()` and now it works just fine ;)

Comment: Huh, all i did was `new File()` with the result of `FileDialog#open()` :)